# Cannot remove script virus in Ubuntu

Tags: security, antivirus, viruses

After I scan via clamav/clamtk, I found 1 possible threat that I cannot remove/quarantine.

How to remove virus? Or Is this false positive?

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rdoc/generator/template/darkfish/js/thickbox-compressed.js

PUA.Script.Packed-1
```

Answer (score 2):

What methods have you already tried to remove it?

A file should always be removable by removing it as root in the terminal with 'sudo rm', so in your case

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rdoc/generator/template/darkfish/js/thickbox-compressed.js
```

This will prompt you for your password, and then the file will be removed

If this doesn't work, somethings definitely wierd